# PHP dynamically created $_SESSION associative array

Tags: php, arrays, class, session

I'm trying to create a PHP Session Wrapper Class and to do it - in order to make it flexible I need to be able to dynamically create session associative array like so:

```
'basket' => array(
   27 => array(
      'colour' => 'blue',
      'qty' => 2,
      'price' => 20.50
   )
)
```

The way to set the session would be by calling:

```
Session::set(array('basket', $item_id, 'colour'), 'blue');
Session::set(array('basket', $item_id, 'qty'), 2);
Session::set(array('basket', $item_id, 'price'), 20.50);
```

Now - I'm really not sure how to create session associative array out of the first parameter of the set() method.

It might be just one item or more than 4 presented here - the idea is to make it dynamic - regardless of number of items in the first array parameter.

Any idea how could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are saying.  The following code is messy, but it is a proof of concept.  The method you are suggesting allows you to reset a deeper value without resetting the entire array, which I believe this accomplishes (up to four keys in array).  You'll need to do some validation to make sure that the array indices are actually set to prevent any errors, but it will work fine after that.

```
class SessionWrapper
{
    public static function set($key, $value)
    {
        if (is_array($key)) {
            $keyCount = count($key);
            switch ($keyCount) {
                case 1:
                    $_SESSION[$key[0]] = $value;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $_SESSION[$key[0]][$key[1]] = $value;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $_SESSION[$key[0]][$key[1]][$key[2]] = $value;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $_SESSION[$key[0]][$key[1]][$key[2]][$key[3]] = $value;
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        return true;
    }
}


// single level
SessionWrapper::set('veggies', array(
    $veg_id => array(
        'color' => 'green'
    )
));

// three keys deep
SessionWrapper::set(array('veggies', $veg_id, 'color'), 'green');

// four keys deep
SessionWrapper::set(array('states', 'PA', 'senators', 1), 'Robert Casey');

// array(
//     'states' => array(
//         'PA' => array(
//             'senators' => array(
//                 1 => 'Robert Casey'
//             )
//         )
//     )
// )
```

Comment: Is this preferable from `$_SESSION['states']['PA']['senators'][1] = 'Robert Casey';`?

Comment: Yes - it actually is - easier to manage with some situations when you don't quite know how many items might be there - I understand that not everyone needs it, but that's exactly what was needed for the purpose of my application. Still - I'm limited to the manually defined numer of cases so if there was a chance for array which has more than 4 items then I would have to create addditional case, but it will do for now. Thank you for your imput guys - much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

What's so wrong about this?

```
$_SESSION['basket'] = array(
     27 => array(
        'colour' => 'blue',
        'qty' => 2,
        'price' => 20.50));
```

I think you are trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. What functionality does your session class offer that PHP's session facilities do not?

Comment: There's nothing wrong about it - except the fact that I'm creating the wrapper class - therefore I would like to make it more flexible and easier to use.

Comment: I think what he is saying is that: Session::set(array('basket', $item_id, 'colour'));
is the exact same as $_SESSION['myArray'] = array('basket', $item_id, 'colour'); he's wondering what the wrapper class does that PHP's normal session handling doesn't which would include the reason to redo all the work that PHP already does for you.

Comment: If it is just to prevent coding in session_start(); at the beginning of every page, just add it once to your header file and voila.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public function set($key, $arrayOrVar) {
   $_SESSION[$key] = $arrayOrVar;
   return $_SESSION[$key];
   }
```

??  Just send it an array and it will sessionize it (<- I'm totally copyrighting that term)

Maybe I misunderstood, is there any reason for your session class to be doing all the array jumbling work when it seems like that should be the job of your code, not your standard includes that never change.

Comment: The thing I'm trying to achieve with calling Session::set(array('basket', $item_id, 'colour'), 'blue'); is $_SESSION['basket'][$item_id]['colour'] = 'blue'